# Consuming sequence inside a embeddedId in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, composite-key, database-sequence

I have the next issue -> I have a table on my db with a composite id...
Supose (Id1,Id2,Id3,Id4), the Id4 is generated by a sequence on the db...

My question is, in spring boot, I generate the entity 'Table1' and the corresponding 'Table1Id',
but when i want to add the corresponding GeneratedValue from the sequence, is not generating anything.

I was looking for in the internet and i found that the GeneratedValue is not working without the @Id anotation, but maybe there are some way to fix this issue.

Thank's and sorry for my english.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

When a composite id is required in your project, it is impossible with an embeddedId.  It is necesary to use @IdClass on my compossiteId instead @EmbeddedId, because the second does not work with @GeneratedValues for example my solution was:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "table_name")
@IdClass(CompositeIdTest.class)
public class TestClass implements Serializable {



    @Id
    @Column(name = "column", nullable = false)
    private String column;


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence")
    private int idGenerated;
```

Anyway, thank's